# Skipping Postgres specific test using importorskip

Tags: python, postgresql, pytest

I have a module with tests written using py.test.
It has a number of different functions performing the same actions against different database backends - primarily sqlite and PostgreSQL.

I'd like to only run the PostgreSQL tests if the database is installed. My initial thought was to use the `pytest.importorskip` mark and check to see if `psycopg2` is installed. This may be a little too successful though as it is skipping these tests on all of my VMs even when `psycopg2` is installed.

When I run `py.test -rs` on the VM with PostgreSQL installed I see this in the output:

```
SKIP [1] /home/andy47/pf/test_populate.py:30: could not import 'psycopg2'
SKIP [1] /home/andy47/pf/test_populate.py:25: could not import 'psycopg2'
```

But when I run python I can import the module:

```
$ python
>>> import psycopg2
>>> psycopg2.__version__
'2.6 (dt dec pg3 ext lo64)'
```

Could this import issue be caused by me running the application in a virtualenv?

Comment: In `/home/andy47/pf/test_populate.py:30`, try to explicitly import `pyscopg2` before your `pytest.importorskip` command to see if that works... if it works, I'm guessing it might be a problem with pytest, otherwise your environment is not properly configured as you thought.

Comment: The import is fine and doesn't throw an exception. So it looks like I'm doing something wrong with either pytest or the environment.

Comment: Well, an workaround would be to manually `import psycopg2`, and skip it explicitly using a try/except and a `pytest.skip(reason)` call, but I would try to investigate your environment in more detail as your approach should work. Btw, how are you creating your virtual environment? Are you by any change using `--no-site-packages` or `--system-site-packages` options?